# Two ArrayList on an Adapter ArrayList<ArrayList<ExpenseData>> expenseData how to get the next position

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So finally after two weeks of struggle I was able to solve my problem and now I get to display everything the way I wanted, However i want to know when you declare your data like this `ArrayList<ArrayList<ExpenseData>> expenseData;` on an `onBindViewHolder` how do you get the position?

trying `expenseData.get(position).get(0).getCurrency()`

I am getting an

> ```
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> ```

I want to fix this **holder**

```
 holder1.setWalletAmountView("$"+ Double.valueOf(walletBalance).toString());
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class TransactionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionsAdapter.GeneralViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<ExpenseData>> expenseData;
    private final Activity activity;
    private final double walletBalance;
    private final double totalExpenseAmount;

    public TransactionsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ArrayList<ExpenseData>> expenseData, double walletBalance, double totalExpenseAmount) {
        this.expenseData = expenseData;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.walletBalance = walletBalance;
        this.totalExpenseAmount = totalExpenseAmount;
    }
```

Comment: Post your whole adapter code please ?

Comment: @SushilKumar done.

Comment: you need an extra loop for the iterating inner list by the size of an individual list. maybe one of your list sizes is zero that why you are getting an error. and before this,  check you upper list size and comment all the code.

Comment: `expenseData.get(position).get(0)` here you are getting one of the inner ArrayList size is zero every time you have to check the inner size.

Comment: Show the data. it says your arraylist is having size 0. just verify the data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the inner list size before getting data...

```
 if (amount < 0){

 int size=expenses.get(i).getExpenseDataList.size();

 if(size>0){

 for(int j=0;j<size;j++{

            holder1.setTotalExpenseAmount(expenseData.get(position).get(0).getCurrency() + " " + Double.valueOf(amount * (-1)).toString());
        else
            holder1.setTotalExpenseAmount(expenseData.get(position).get(0).getCurrency() + " " + Double.valueOf(amount).toString()); 
    }
    }
    }
```

surely you will make a getter setter for the upper `ArrayList` and  get the size of an inner list by like

```
 int size=expenses.get(i).getExpenseDataList.size();
```

if you want only `index 0` you just need to get the size of inner lists and no need of any internal loop inside `onBindView()`. the size must be greater than zero.